# How to retrieve a cookie in R Apache

Tags: apache, r, cookies, rapache

How do I get the cookie's value in R-Apache?

I set the cookie in my html code using brew
:

`setCookie(name="ID",value=paste(sample(1:9999,1)))`

My page has a form that sends post data to my R code. How would I be able to retrieve this cookie in the R code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with [RApache's built-in variable](http://rapache.net/manual.html#rapache_Variables): `COOKIES`. Short example:

```
setCookie(name="ID",value=paste(sample(1:9999,1)))
cat(COOKIES[["ID"]])
```